# Assign float * or int * to mxArray

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I got a typical cpp function in matlab using mex

```
#include "mex.h"

void func (int * rowvec, int * colvec, float * valvec, int * nnz){/*fill arguments*/}



void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
                 int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
```

where I check that in I have enough output variables available

```
if(nlhs != 4) {
  mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("MyToolbox:arrayProduct:nlhs",
                  "Four outputs required.");
}
```

Furthermore, in this function I declare four variables:

```
int *rowvec;        /* 1st output array */
int *colvec;        /* 2nd output array */
float *valvec;      /* 3rd output array */
int *nnz;           /* 4th output scalar */
```

They will be defined/filled in a function:

```
func(rowvec, colvec, valvec, nnz) //arguments get filled with values
```

Now I want to do something like that:

```
plhs[0] = rowvec;
plhs[1] = colvec;
plhs[2] = valvec;
plhs[3] = nnz;
```

It unfortunately throws four understandable errors, because those are two different data types. The errors are like this:

```
cannot convert ‘int*’ to ‘mxArray* {aka mxArray_tag*}’ in assignment plhs[0] = rowvec;
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I'm writing this in matlab, but it's a c++ file, I did it accoringly to this tutorial: http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/standalone-example.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a step.

You need to use [mxCreateNumericArray](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxcreatenumericarray.html?searchHighlight=mxcreatenumericarray) and assign that to your output arguments.

Then use mxGetData on the created arrays and set your int/float pointers to that.

Then call func to fill the outputs.

```
plhs[0] = mxCreateNumericArray(ndim, *dims, classid, ComplexFlag);
...
rowvec=(int*)mxGetData(plhs[0]);
...
func(rowvec, colvec, valvec, nnz);
```

If you can change the interface, you might want to consider func(plhs) instead. You will need to know the size of the output arrays before you can use the pointers.

Comment: As far as I understand `ndim` and `dims` represent the size of, in this case, `rowvec`, right? But what if I don't know the size of rowvec at that time? Actually `*nnz` is an `int` scalar and represents the length of the three vectors `rowvec`, `colvec` and `valvec`.

Comment: Did you miss my edit? 

If the func interface is set, do the mxArray creation after and copy the data.

Comment: Ok, if there is no other possibility I'll copy it. Thank you!

Comment: Another problem arised: the arrays `rowvec`, etc. will be filled in `func`, and they are filled correctly (I double checked), but as soon as I leave `func` the arrays are filled with 0's, i.e. a for loop over `rowvec` within `mexFunction` prints 0's?! Why do I loose the values?

Comment: It's ok. I could fix it already. Thank you very much for your help!